# how to restore deleted user account through sitecore

Tags: user-management

Could you please share, how we can check, if *who* has *deleted* `user account` and how we can *restore* the deleted user account in Sitecore, without writing any code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I checked in my Sitecore solution is when we create a user it inserts an entry in the `[aspnet_Users]` table in core database. And when you delete it, it removes the entry in the database.

So I think there is no way to restore the deleted user account as far as you have an old backup of your database.

But you may try by [recover](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/recover-deleted-records-in-sql-server/) delete rows in SQL table may be you can get something by not sure.

Another thing is the history who deleted the user and yes you can get the details in your log files. When I deleted a user it added an entry in my log file like this.

```
28676 15:05:38 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\Admin): Delete user: sitecore\testuser
```

using this code

```
Log.Audit(owner, "Delete user: {0}", userName);
```

So check your logs and you will find the related information .

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is NO such provision available out of the box.

I know you are not looking for custom code but since it's not possible without code, I am sharing a useful series of article.

- https://walidrohiman.wordpress.com/2023/09/15/sitecore-restore-deleted-users-part-1/
- https://walidrohiman.wordpress.com/2023/09/29/sitecore-restore-deleted-users-part-2/
- https://walidrohiman.wordpress.com/2023/10/08/sitecore-restore-deleted-users-part-3/

Hope this helps.